# Why don't mails show up in the recipient's mailspool?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, postfix

I have postfix dovecot running with local email system on thunderbird. I have two users on by ubuntu, mailuser 1 and mailuser 2 whom i added to thunderbird. Everything went fine, except the users dont have anything on their inbox on thunderbird and sent mails dont get through.

Im using maildir as well. Checking /var/log/mail.log reveals this

This what is happining: Restarting postfix and dovecot and then sending mail from one user to another user...

I believe this line is the problem

```
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/smtpd[12804]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

Why is it not connecting ? What could be wrong ?

/var/log/mail.log

```
May 30 18:30:21 dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
May 30 18:30:21 dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
May 30 18:30:21 dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=467 out=475
May 30 18:30:21 dovecot: config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
May 30 18:30:21 dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
May 30 18:30:21 dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
May 30 18:30:21 dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)
May 30 18:30:54 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mailuser2>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=12638, TLS, session=<xUfQkaD66gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
May 30 18:31:04 postfix/master[12245]: terminating on signal 15
May 30 18:31:04 postfix/master[12795]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/postscreen[12803]: CONNECT from [127.0.0.1]:33668 to [127.0.0.1]:25
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/postscreen[12803]: WHITELISTED [127.0.0.1]:33668
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/smtpd[12804]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/smtpd[12804]: 1ED7120EB9: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/cleanup[12809]: 1ED7120EB9: message-id=<5388B27A.7060709@s148134.com>
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/qmgr[12799]: 1ED7120EB9: from=<mailuser1@mysite.com>, size=546, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/local[12810]: 1ED7120EB9: to=<mailuser2@mysitecom>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/qmgr[12799]: 1ED7120EB9: removed
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/smtpd[12804]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 30 18:31:55 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mailuser1>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=12814, TLS, session=<sD9plaD6PgB/AAAB>
```

This is my postfix main.cf

```
 See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific: Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name. The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
 biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h
 readme_directory = no
# TLS parameters
 smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
 smtpd_use_tls=yes
 smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
 smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
  # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
 # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
 smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated           
 defer_unauth_destination
 myhostname = server
 mydomain = mysite.com
 alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
 myorigin = $mydomain
 mydestination = mysite.com
 #relayhost = smtp.192.168.10.1.com
 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.10.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox = Maildir /
mailbox_command=
```

All ports are listening

```
tcp 0 0 *:imaps *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 *:submission *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 *:imap2 *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 s148134.s148134.:domain *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 192.168.56.101:domain *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 10.0.2.15:domain *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 localhost:domain *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 *:ssh *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 *:smtp *:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 localhost:953 *:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:imaps [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:submission [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:imap2 [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:domain [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:ssh [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:smtp [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 localhost:953 [::]:* LISTEN
```

Comment: Your log shows that you restarted the services and the mail was delivered successfully.

Comment: How come thunderbird inbox is empty then ?  Do i need to adjust any settings on thunderbird maybe ?

Comment: I have no idea. Your logs do not show the recipient checking mail _after_ it was delivered, only _before_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, seeing the disconnect is normal, and it is not an error of any kind. That is because it is preceded by a successful delivery:

```
May 30 18:31:55 postfix/local[12810]: 1ED7120EB9: to=<mailuser2@mysitecom>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
```

Note the `status=sent` part; that indicates that the message was successfully delivered to its target location as far as the logging server's configuration is concerned. In this case, that was local delivery to a maildir spool, so **the message is sitting somewhere** waiting to be picked up.

What you need to do is **confirm** that Postfix is placing the mail messages *where Dovecot is looking.* They both can be configured to use an arbitrary location to store the mail spool; the two must be the same, or mail will appear to be delivered but never show up to a MUA.

On the Postfix side, [`$home_mailbox`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox) controls delivery location under each user's home directory. Appending a `/` selects "qmail-style delivery"; A.K.A., maildir. **You have a space in there;** you should probably change your Postfix configuration to read `home_mailbox = Maildir/` without the space before the forward slash.

On the Dovecot side, the configuration value `mail_location` selects the directory in which to look for mail. It supports the standard `~` for the user's home directory, and must specify the mail spool format. So in Dovecot, you need to set `mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir` (check to make sure only one such directive is in effect). On my Debian Wheezy system, this happens to be configured in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf.

Having made these changes, delete any existing mail spool file or directory for the user in question and send another e-mail. It should be delivered fine by Postfix, and then available for picking up through Dovecot.